# UTF-8 encoding in str type Python 2

Tags: python, utf-8, base64

I have a Python 2.7 code which retrieves a base64 encoded response from a server. This response is decoded using `base64` module (`b64decode` / `decodestring` functions, returning `str`). Its decoded content has the Unicode code points of the original strings.

I need to convert these Unicode code points to UTF-8.

The original string has a substring content "Não". When I decode the responded string, it shows:

```
>>> encoded_str = ... # server response
>>> decoded_str = base64.b64decode(encoded_str)
>>> type(decoded_str)
<type 'str'>
>>> decoded_str[x:y]
'N\xe3o'
```

When I try to encode to UTF-8, it leads to errors as

```
>>> (decode_str[x:y]).encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, when this string is manually written in Unicode type, I can correctly convert it to my desired UTF-8 string.

```
>>> test_str = u'N\xe3o'
>>> test.encode('utf-8')
'N\xc3\xa3o'
```

I have to retrieve this response from the server and correctly generate an UTF-8 string which can be printed as "Não", how can I do this in Python 2?

Comment: Probably decode as Latin-1

Comment: What happens when you do `print decoded_str[x:y]` ?

Answer (score 2):

You want to `decode`, not `encode` the byte string.

Think of it like this: a Unicode string was encoded into bytes, and these bytes were further encoded into base64.

To reverse this, you need to reverse both encodings, in the opposite order.

**However,** the sample you show most definitely isn't a valid UTF-8 byte string - 0xE3 in isolation is not a valid UTF-8 encoding. Most likely, the Unicode string was encoded using Latin-1 or a related encoding (the sample is much too small to establish this conclusively; other common candidates are the fugly Windows code page CP1252 and Latin-9).